# Trigger to insert same table after condition is satsified

Tags: sql, triggers

I want to insert a row if the field 'Rem' is yes. I am using triggers. Here the issue is I want to insert the data in the same table. Could you please let me know if you have come across this scenario?

Example:

```sql
create table Table1 
( 
    id int, 
    name varchar(100), 
    is_rem varchar(20) 
);

create or replace trigger Table1Trigger 
after insert 
on Table1 
for each row 
    when (new.is_rem ='yes') 
begin 
    insert into Table1 (id, name, is_rem) 
    values (:new.id, :new.name, :new.is_rem); 
end; /
```

If I am inserting the is_rem as yes, the table should have two rows of the same data.

Comment: First, make up your mind: which database are you using? Can't be MySQL and MS SQL Server (and, possibly, Oracle) at the same time. I mean, it *can* be, but it's most probably not. As different databases use different syntax, solution depends on that tiny piece of information.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; you need to [edit] the correct tag(s) back.

Comment: I also suggest you start getting in the habit of using line breaks and whitespace; your code is impossible to read easily.

Answer (score 0):

Below should works in MySQL

```
create table if not exists Table1 ( id int, name varchar(100), is_rem varchar(20) );

insert into Table1
select new_id as id, new_name as name, new_is_rem as is_rem
from Table2 where new_is_rem = 'yes';
```

Comment: I have only one table which is table1

Comment: If you have already a data with table1, Then why are you creating a Table1 again.

Comment: if you want to make just two same row data in the table where "is_rem = yes" then just edit Table1 instead of Table2 from above query and remove "new_" column name, that's it.

Comment: new_is_rem - SQL developer shows this is an invalid identifier.

Comment: insert into Table1
select *
from Table1 where is_rem = 'yes';

Comment: Mutating trigger error.